# How to fix CSS menu bug

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS3 Menu. When a menu items text is too long the design breaks. I want the text to simply move up to fit
the text. For example: At www.casa.gov.au the menu item text REGULATIONS AND POLICY starts higher than the rest
of the items. This prevents the menu width and height changing to fit the larger text.

How would I go about doing this with the menu attached in the JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/UU4rm/

The problem is associated with the line height at #css li a { }

## CSS CODE

```
/* MENU */
 #cssmenu {
    border:none;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgb(77,77,77);
}
#cssmenu ul {
    background:#333333;
    height:39px;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu li {
    padding:0px;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 115px;
}
#cssmenu li a {
    background:#333333 url('../images/seperator.gif') bottom right no-repeat;
    color:#FFF;
    display:block;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:39px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 0px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    width: 115px;
}
#cssmenu li a:hover, 
#cssmenu ul li:hover a,
#cssmenu li a:focus, 
#cssmenu ul li:focus a{
    background: #2580a2;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    float: none;
}
#cssmenu li ul {
    background:#333333;
    display:none;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:230px;
    z-index:200;
    /*top:1em;
    /*left:0;*/
}
#cssmenu li.force-show ul,
#cssmenu li:hover ul,
#cssmenu li a:focus + ul{
    display:block;
}
#cssmenu li li {
    background:url('../images/sub_sep.gif') bottom left no-repeat;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:230px;
}
#cssmenu li:hover li a, 
#cssmenu li:focus li a {
    background:none;
}
#cssmenu li ul a {
    display:block;
    height:35px;
    font-size:11px;
    font-style:normal;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 15px;
    text-align:left;
    width: 205px;
}
#cssmenu li ul a:hover, 
#cssmenu li ul li:hover a,
#cssmenu li ul a:focus, 
#cssmenu li ul li:focus a{
    background:#2580a2 url('../images/hover_sub.gif') center left no-repeat;
    border:0px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    width: 205px;
}
#cssmenu p {
    clear:left;
}
:focus {
    outline:none;
}
::-moz-focus-inner {
    border:0;
}
```

## HTML CODE

```
<div id="cssmenu">                                  <ul>                <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:HOMEPAGE:1017433626:pc=PC_90001">Home</a></li>         
                    <li class="has-sub">                <a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90002">Operations</a>                <ul>            
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90003">Individuals</a>                       
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90123">Aircraft owners</a>                       
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90276">Aircraft operators</a>                        
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90389">Flight training</a>                       
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90405">Aerodromes</a>                        
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90447">Office of airspace regulation</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_93439">Sport aviation</a>                        
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_93379">Class D</a>                       
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_100058">Non-towered aerodromes</a>                       
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90385">Dangerous goods</a>                       
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_100808">Ground operations</a>                        
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_100847">Non-compliance notice</a>                        
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_100374">Unmanned Aircraft Systems (UAS)</a>                      
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_100705">General Aviation (GA) task force </a>                        
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_100852">Regional Aviation Safety Forum (RASF)</a>                        
      </li>
                    <li><a href="http://casa.gov.au/aod" target="_top">Drug and Alcohol Management Plans</a>                        
      </li>
                    </ul></li>          
                    <li class="has-sub">                <a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90473">Airworthiness</a>             <ul>            
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_100610">Maintenance regulations</a>                      
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90474">Personnel</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90496">Certification and design</a>                      
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90507">Manufacturing</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90515">Continuing airworthiness</a>                      
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90822">Airworthiness directives</a>                      
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90821">Maintenance organisations</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_101038">Flight test and evaluation</a>                       
      </li>
                    </ul></li>          
                    <li class="has-sub">                <a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90900">Regulations &amp; Policy</a>              <ul>            
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90902">Current rules</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:PWA:1017433626:pc=PC_91070">Changing the rules</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91181">Enforcement action</a>                        
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:PWA:1017433626:pc=PC_91190">Policy notices</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_100396">Australia's state safety program</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_101078">Performance based navigation (PBN)</a>                       
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_101326">Licensing regulations</a>                        
      </li>
                    </ul></li>          
                    <li class="has-sub">                <a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91263">Manuals &amp; forms</a>               <ul>            
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91264">Manuals</a>                       
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91308">Forms</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91316">CASA online store</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_101402">Temporary Management Instructions (TMIs)</a>                     
      </li>
                    </ul></li>          
                    <li class="has-sub">                <a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91314">Education</a>             <ul>            
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_101349">AviationWorx</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_100101">eLearning catalogue</a>                      
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91346">Flight Safety Australia</a>                       
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_90006"> Pilot guides and information </a>                        
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_100138">OnTrack</a>                      
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_100994">Human factors</a>                        
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91430">Safety management systems</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91329">Seminars and workshops</a>                        
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91317">Aviation safety advisers</a>                      
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91455">Advice for air travellers</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91316">CASA online store</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_101317">Out-n-Back</a>                       
      </li>
                    </ul></li>          
                    <li class="has-sub">                <a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91488">Services</a>              <ul>            
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91489">Licences &amp; registrations</a>                      
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:SSP:1017433626:pc=PC_91499">Self Service Portal</a>                        
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91510">Service standards &amp; fees</a>                      
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91517">Permission application centre (PAC)</a>                       
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91521">Aviation medicals</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_100450">Delegates and authorised persons</a>                     
      </li>
                    </ul></li>          
                    <li class="has-sub">                <a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91621">About CASA</a>                <ul>            
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91622">Contact CASA</a>                      
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_93342">CASA board</a>                        
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91668">CASA's Director</a>                       
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_91703">Recent media releases</a>                     
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_92568">Corporate publications</a>                        
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_100448">CASA on Twitter</a>                      
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_92918">Corporate policy</a>                      
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_92936">Careers at CASA</a>                       
      </li>
                    <li><a href="HTTP://wcmstest/scripts/nc.dll?WCMS:STANDARD:1017433626:pc=PC_92956">Research and statistics</a>                       
      </li>
                    </ul></li>          
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please be more concise in your question - try to isolate it. You're presenting so much code now that most people will not even bother trying to dive into it. [Read up on the SSCCE principle.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions)

Comment: You could get [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or use [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to find out how they did it on http://www.casa.gov.au `Right-click -> "Inspect element"` and checking the CSS rules that apply on the element is a lot less effort than crafting a good SO question. And +1 to @Niels, with that much code you make me feel like I'm doing your job, and then I can't be bothered.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me (in FF), that it's the bottom border attribute that's causing a goofy black line under your menu.

```
#cssmenu {
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgb(77,77,77);
}
```

Eliminating that bottom border attribute, and adding addition text to the menu items (causing a wrap/second line) acted as expected.